# Regex pattern classification for Java?

Tags: java, regex, recommendation-engine

For example, I want to classify c*t => CLASS1, and d*g => CLASS2:

```
Pattern CXT = Pattern.compile("^c.*t$");
Pattern DXG = Pattern.compile("^d.*g$");

public int classify(String in) {
    if (CXT.matches(in)) return CLASS1;
    if (DXG.matches(in)) return CLASS2;
    return -1;
}
```

It's very inefficient if there are a lot of mode patterns.

Assume all patterns are orthogonal, it's easy to see a single pass in one DFA is enough. So, is there exist such regex processor which could combine all patterns together?

Comment: In what way is this related to Java?

Comment: How can you not lose information? (i.e. C and D are distinct returns)

Comment: Is there a relationship between the first letter of the pattern and the letter you are returning?

Comment: Well, I'd like to know an open source Java library which will compile multiple Patterns into one, and tell which Pattern the input string is accepted by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [**dk.brics.automaton**](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/) package, which is not exactly what you're looking for, but it's a really fast **state machine** implementation with *BSD license*.

So you can build up your automaton which does the classification for you faster than a regular expression.

Comment: I've checked the api through, and Yes it is.

Comment: there is a `BasicOperations.union()` which maybe helps you to combine your previously built Automatons.

Answer (score 0):

You could do e.g. (not tested):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^((c.*t)|(d.*g))$");


public int classify(String in) {
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(in);
    if (m.matches()) {
        if ( m.group(2) != null ) {
             return C;
        }
        else if ( m.group(3) != null ) {
         return D;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

but I'm not sure this would be any more efficient than your current code. Either way, you've got to compare your input for all possible patterns, whether you do it explicitly or build it into the regex

Comment: You need parens around the options, as written the ^ applies to cxt and the $ applies to dxg.

Comment: In `Pattern` implementation, `'|'` seems be compiled to `Pattern.Branch`, however, it just iterates over all branches, not combine or merge them in DFA graph.

Comment: I don't believe there is a DFA graph for this problem which is fundamentally different from N separate sub-DFAs where the DFA can distinguish cat from dot and there are distinct stop states for each language you are matching.  There are no states in common except for the start state and the ^ match.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^((c.*t)|(d.*g))$/
```

You then look to see which match was found.  If you see $2, then return CLASS1.  If you see $3, return CLASS2, etc.